# Using Bitblt to screenshot

Tags: vb.net, winapi

I'm looking for the fastest way to take a print-screen, and i found out that using Bitblt was my better choice, however, it only works for device context handle's, which means for me to retrieve a bitmap from that, i'd have to use multiple API's including CreateCompatibleBitmap, which in the end it probably takes the same time as using a managed way, like graphics.CopyFromScreen (which is a bit slow for me and also consumes alot of CPU, between 7-10% on a 2.3ghz quad-core processor...)

However, i still searched for a cleaner way of retrieving a bitmap from it, so i came up with this code:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Public Shared Function GetDC(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Public Shared Function ReleaseDC(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal hDC As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("gdi32.dll")> _
Public Shared Function BitBlt(ByVal hdcDest As IntPtr, ByVal xDest As Integer, ByVal yDest As Integer, ByVal wDest As Integer, ByVal hDest As Integer, ByVal hdcSource As IntPtr, _
ByVal xSrc As Integer, ByVal ySrc As Integer, ByVal rop As TernaryRasterOperations) As Boolean
End Function

    Dim hwNd As IntPtr = Nothing

    hwNd = GetDC(GetDesktopWindow)

    picHandle = GetDC(Me.PictureBox1.Handle)

    BitBlt(picHandle, 0, 0, PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height, hwNd, 0, 0, TernaryRasterOperations.SRCCOPY)

    ReleaseDC(hwNd, picHandle)
```

I can reach ~30 fps with this... But it has two problems as i said above:

Even if displaying it on a picturebox as i'm doing it above accomplished what i want, it doesn't resize to the picturebox control, even if i change those "0" values to the picturebox x and y coordinates.
I further searched and found there's a StretchBit API for that, and it does stretch, but it also reduces quality, (Even with the necessary call to SetStretchBltMode with parameter "HALFTONE" so it doesn't "corrupt" the pixels), it also reduces performance at least in 10+ fps...

But as i need to get it as bitmap object, with the other necessary API's for that, i ended up with almost half the performance (15~ fps) which is equivalent of graphics.CopyFromScreen.

So, i'm asking, is there another way to get a bitmap from the screen using Bitblt or similar without losing performance?

If there isn't a .Net way, i kindly ask for any language-way of doing that.

Comment: Your performance is very strange. 30fps is using GDI+ not GDI. With bitblt you get around 600-800 fps and stretchblt is some times faster. Did you managed to find a solution?

Comment: 600-800 fps? What do you mean? I'm asking this because it seems impossible...
You can test the code to confirm what i said, i just want a stable way to at least 25 fps.
I still didn't found a solution using .net.

Comment: Ok, 800 fps is when you bitblt a compatible dc, because this dc is on video memory. With your example I am getting with HALFTONE and stretchblt around 250 fps because it involves software. I am using `QueryPerformanceCounter` to measure time.

Comment: I dont even have a graphic card. If i did then the performance whould explode even more.

Comment: But you're using c++ right? I'm using a timer with 1s tick to reset the fps counter, which tops 31...

Comment: I am using c, but it doesn't matter because you are calling the same api's. The problem with the timer is its interval which is around 16msec or 60fps. So you cannot measure anything larger than 60. I will give you a code snippet.

Comment: But no, it still tops 30 fps with the stopwatch class...

Answer (score 0):

If you want raw performance, you will have to get away from managed code. This is easy enough using C++ with Visual Studio. You can make calls directly to the Windows API, bypassing the .NET runtime, managed code for your application, and the overhead of p/invokes in .NET.

If you are familiar with C#, you can take your C# code, convert it to C++ (which should be straightforward, with a lot of work to replace the CLI).

Comment: Well, i never worked with c++, can i make it as a dll or something that i can call it from .net, will that be fast enough, since i still have to import it?

Comment: You are essentially doing the same thing with the p/invokes to the Windows API. I just realized that you are blting into a picturebox. You can also blt into the form itself (removing the picturebox) which will give you some additional fps. You will have to override the on paint event (maybe it is on drawn, it has been a while since I have done graphics processing at that level).

Comment: My goal was as i explained above (i know my post is long.. :p), is to know the fastest way to get a bitmap from the "desktopwindow" like print-screen button to send over tcp to another application.
Currently i got a stable 15~ fps that the other application receives, i'm taking a screenshot and converting it to bitmap in approximately 60-70 ms, i guess that's the best i can do with .net, since in total i'm making 8 API calls and further converting it to bitmap and to bytes right after.

But in the end, this is almost equal as using a managed function as g.CopyFromScreen...

Comment: I probably will at least try to convert this code to c/c++ and get a performance counter in fps, if it's too much difference, i'll probably try to make a dll out of it and call it from the .net application or something.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Declare Function BitBlt Lib "GDI32" ( _
    ByVal hdcDest As Integer, _
    ByVal nXDest As Integer, _
    ByVal nYDest As Integer, _
    ByVal nWidth As Integer, _
    ByVal nHeight As Integer, _
    ByVal hdcSrc As Integer, _
    ByVal nXSrc As Integer, _
    ByVal nYSrc As Integer, _
    ByVal dwRop As System.Int32) As Boolean

Declare Function QueryPerformanceCounter Lib "Kernel32" (ByRef X As Long) As Short
Declare Function QueryPerformanceFrequency Lib "Kernel32" (ByRef X As Long) As Short

Const SRCCOPY As Integer = &HCC0020
```

Use a form with only a picturebox and a label in it. Set the anchors of picbox accordingly. In picbox down event:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
    Dim Ctr1, Ctr2, Freq As Long
    Dim dbl As Double

    QueryPerformanceCounter(Ctr1)


    Dim desktopDC As IntPtr = Nothing
    Dim picboxDC As IntPtr = Nothing

    desktopDC = GetDC(New IntPtr(0))

    picboxDC = GetDC(PictureBox1.Handle)

    BitBlt(picboxDC, 0, 0, PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height, desktopDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY)

    QueryPerformanceCounter(Ctr2)
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(Freq)

    dbl = (Ctr2 - Ctr1) / Freq

    dbl *= 1000000

    Label1.Text = dbl.ToString 'it is in microseconds

    ReleaseDC(New IntPtr(0), desktopDC)
    ReleaseDC(PictureBox1.Handle, picboxDC)

End Sub
```

Maximize your form and click in picturebox.

Comment: Well, it gives me [this](http://i.imgur.com/TVZv6H8.png)

It is 32~ fps, which is almost the same as my example above.. and i still can't get a bitmap from Bitblt alone

Comment: @SomeNickName I will try to see a directx solution then

Comment: Does it in C have better performance? If there's no other option, i can try learning the required API's and hopefully the little sintax needed to accomplish that in C/C++..